# Top Margin / Overlay and Hiding Elements

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

https://www.insure.report/en

I need to fix the Updates widget to have a top margin so it isn't covered by the header **OR** I need the widget to load on top of the header, not behind it.

Then I need to hide the 'Submit an idea' link.

I'm still new to CSS and the Submit link uses several classes so I don't know which to set to display none.

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I configured it according to https://help.frill.co/article/75-adding-the-widget

It's not really the right answer because what I was seeking was not done. But I removed the top elements instead.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your html and css it's hard to be absolutely positive but I gave the `id` `frill` in dev tools a property and value `margin-top: 20px` and that seems to solve your first question in dev tools. Since you are using bootstrap, in your custom CSS stylesheet you'll probably want to add:

```
#frill {
    margin-top: 20px!important;
}
```

For the submit link you could give that link a class, like `class="hide-link"` in your html and then give that class a CSS rule of `display: none;` like:

```
.hide-link {
     display: none!important;
}
```

Comment: I can't add the element to the submit link because it's loaded from another site. The widget's source code is external. It has too many classes so I don't know which to set as display none.

Comment: frill CSS code did not work either. Could you have a look at the page source and CSS? Would really appreciate it!

Comment: @whisky sorry it didn't work. I'd suggest just start trying different classes in your CSS that you see in your html and add the above rules I posted and see which ones work. It's hard for me to tell exactly what's going on just with dev tools. The `margin-top` rule might work for the immediate child div of `#frill`

Comment: class="_1cyFBCS5_Y_nNZVnC0MXsW undefined _3MZe1rEZw8VotOyGyiFOyP _8SE9MEQALrDHZuuVkPc4c">Submit an Idea

Comment: I tried display none for those class names but it still shows

Comment: Sorry it's still not working. How are you setting up this project? If I know more about which technologies you're using maybe I can assist you better.